# How to use tf.image.ssim in tensorflow.js and React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, tensorflow.js

In a **React Native**, in an Expo managed app, I want to retrieve an image(s) from the [ImagePicker](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) and pass it through the `tf.image.ssim` function of tensorflow , here is what I have done so far:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';
import * as FileSystem from 'expo-file-system';

export default function App() {

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const pickImage = async () => {

    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      quality: 1,
    });
    
    const img64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(result.uri, { encoding: 'base64' });
    const rawImageData = tf.util.encodeString(img64, 'base64');

    // Calling tensorflow.image.ssim function FAILS
    tf.image.ssim(rawImageData, rawImageData)

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage({uri: result.uri, fileSize: result.fileSize});
    }
  };
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white", marginTop: 40 }}>
      <Button title="Pick image from camera roll" onPress={pickImage} />
      {image && <Image source={{ uri: image.uri }} style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }} />}
  </View>
  );
}
```

But this returns an error:

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not
> an object (evaluating 'env().platform.encode')

I have been looking on other posts but no post corresponds to this issue.

Any idea ?

Thanks

**p.s:** normally we pass two different images to ssim, but this is just to see if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

entire `tf.image` namespace in `tensorflow` is an add-on.
tfjs implements some of its own `tf.image` methods, but overlap between python `tf.image` namespace and tfjs `tf.image` namespace is *near-zero*.

if you want `.ssim` method, you'd need to implement it yourself in tfjs - it simply does not exist.